# Filters / max min / every nth post?

Tags: ruby, blogs, jekyll, liquid

Let's say I have a `div` container of 3 columns, which I want Jekyll to populate with all posts. I see the `limit` Liquid syntax, but can't figure out how to append the div container below after every 3rd blog. Is this possible?

Let's say I have 9 posts; I should see the 3 columns with 3 rows of `column-container`.

```
{% for post in site.posts %}

<div class="column-container">

   <!-- col 1 -->
   <div class="column">
      <p>1 {{ post.title }}</p>   
   </div>

   <!-- col 2 -->
   <div class="column">
      <p>2 {{ post.title }}</p>   
   </div>

   <!-- col 3 -->
   <div class="column">
      <p>3 {{ post.title }}</p>   
   </div>

</div>

{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using the [cycle filter](http://wiki.shopify.com/UsingLiquid#Cycle) and doing something like this..

```
{% for post in site.posts %}

<div class="column-container">

  <div class="column {%cycle 'col1', 'col2', 'col3'%}">
    <p>1 {{ post.title }}</p>   
  </div>

</div>

{% endfor %}
```

Then use CSS to style them.

```
.column { float: left }
.col1 { clear: left }
```

[See html on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tmvr9/2/)